# AMPScript Sender Profile From Email not resolving

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I have been trying to get this AMPSCRIPT to work for a dynamic from email in the sender profile and nothing seems to be working. I tested the code directly in the email and it works properly, but not in the From Email in the sender profile.:

```
%%[ 
var @email 
Set @email = AttributeValue("Email")
]%%
%%=IIF(EMPTY(AttributeValue("Account")), "x@domain.com", v(@email))=%%
```

or

```
%%[ 
var @name 
Set @name = AttributeValue("Account")
var @email 
Set @email = AttributeValue("Email")
if not empty(@name) or @name == "text string" then set @name = @email
elseif empty(@name) then set @name = "x@domain.com"
endif ]%%
%%=v(@name)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working. Emails need to be verified senders to work. One of them still doesn't work right, but I'll take it at this point.

Comment: You should consider accepting this as a [valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, please accept any other answers to your previous questions.